# X11 : Cannot draw an image on transparent window created with XCreateWindow

Tags: c, image, x11, alpha, xlib

I am trying to create a simple X11 window, which should display a PNG file with transparent areas. I want the window itself to have no (opaque) background, so that the transparent areas in the PNG shows what there is behind the window.

**tl;dr I cannot put an image on a semi-transparent window; it gives "Bad Match".**

I can successfully create a semi-transparent window using XCreateWindow and XMatchVisualInfo :

```
XSetWindowAttributes attr;
attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 
        vinfo.visual, AllocNone);
attr.border_pixel = 0;
attr.background_pixel = 0x80800000; // Red, semi-transparent

Window window = XCreateWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0,
        width, height, 0, vinfo.depth, InputOutput, vinfo.visual,
        CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);
```

*(Full source code below)*

I then create an image using :

```
// "image32" is a generated image - see source code below
XImage *ximage = XCreateImage(display, visual, DefaultDepth(display,DefaultScreen(display)),
        ZPixmap, 0, image32, width, height, 32, 0);
```

And display the image during the `Expose` event :

```
XPutImage(display, window, DefaultGC(display, 0), ximage,
        0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
```

I compile with `gcc test.c -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXrandr -o test` and run with `./test` :

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  72 (X_PutImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  11
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

**Note :** If I replace the lines creating the window (XCreateWindow) with these :

```
Window window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, RootWindow(display, 0), 0, 0,
        width, height, 1, 0, 0);
```

It displays a window correctly; however, there is no transparency.

I read the docs about [XCreateWindow](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XCreateWindow.html), [XPutImage](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XPutImage.html), [XCreateImage](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XCreateImage.html) and tried playing around with multiple parameters, unsuccessfully.

I have read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857575/displaying-png-file-using-xputimage-does-not-work) and tried playing around with color depth; since the docs mentionned "Bad Match" can be also thrown for incorrect visual, I have checked that the same visual was sent at all places in my code.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

**Full source code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

// Window size
int height = 256, width = 256;

XImage *CreateTrueColorImage(Display *display, Visual *visual)
{

    int i, j;
    unsigned char *image32=(unsigned char *)malloc(width*height*4);
    unsigned char *p=image32;
    for(i=0; i<width; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<height;j++)
        {
            *p++ = i;
            *p++ = i;
            *p++ = j;
            *p++ = j; // alpha channel (should progressively get transparent towards left)
        }
    }

    // Replacing "DefaultDepth(display,DefaultScreen(display))" with a hardcoded 
    // 24 or 32 still doesn't work with XCreateWindow. XCreateSimpleWindow works
    // with hardcoded 24, but not 32.
    return XCreateImage(display, visual, DefaultDepth(display,DefaultScreen(display)),
            ZPixmap, 0, image32, width, height, 32, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    XImage *ximage;
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Visual *visual = DefaultVisual(display, 0);

    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    XMatchVisualInfo(display, DefaultScreen(display), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);

    XSetWindowAttributes attr;
    attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 
            vinfo.visual, AllocNone);
    attr.border_pixel = 0;
    attr.background_pixel = 0x80800000; // Red, semi-transparent

    //Window window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, RootWindow(display, 0), 0, 0,
    //      width, height, 1, 0, 0);
    Window window = XCreateWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0,
            width, height, 0, vinfo.depth, InputOutput, vinfo.visual,
            CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);

    ximage = CreateTrueColorImage(display, vinfo.visual);
    XSelectInput(display, window, ButtonPressMask|ExposureMask);
    XMapWindow(display, window);

    while(1)
    {
        XEvent event;
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
        case Expose:
            XPutImage(display, window, DefaultGC(display, 0), ximage,
                    0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
            break;
        case ButtonPress:
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to make it work by making two changes. 
First, instead of using `DefaultGC(display, 0)` you should create a GC for your specific window.

```
GC gc = XCreateGC(display, window, 0, 0);
```

With that if you hardcode the depth of `XCreateImage` to 32 it should work correctly.
And you can also use the depth provided by `XVisualInfo` like so

```
XCreateImage(display, vinfo.visual, vinfo.depth,
        ZPixmap, 0, image32, width, height, 32, 0);
```